# What programming language is Solidity based on?

Tags: solidity

Is Solidity based on some general purpose programming language or domain specific language? Which code is it most similar to (i.e. Python, Rust or Haskell), and considered to have taken its syntax and structuring conventions from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/) (emphasis added):

> Solidity is a curly-bracket language designed to target the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM). **It is influenced by C++, Python and JavaScript.**

You can read more in their [language influences](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/language-influences.html) section.